# C design pattern performing a list of actions without blocking?

Tags: c, design-patterns, embedded, state-machine, event-driven

Embedded C. I have a list of things I want to do, procedurally, mostly READ and WRITE and MODIFY actions, acting on the results of the last statement. They can take up to 2 seconds each, I can’t block.

Each action can have states of COMPLETE and ERROR which has sub-states for reason the error occurred. Or on compete I’ll want to check or modify some data.

Each list of actions is a big switch and to re-enter I keep a list of which step I’m on, a success step++ and I come back in further down the list next time.

Pretty simple, but I’m finding that to not block I’m spending a ton of effort checking states and errors and edges constantly. Over and over.

I would say 80% of my code is just checks and moving the system along. There has to be a better way!

Are there any design patterns for async do thing and come back later for results in a way that efficiently handles some of the exception/edge/handling?

Edit: I know how to use callbacks but don’t really see that as “a solution” as I just need to get back to a different part of the same list for the next thing to do. Maybe it’s would be beneficial to know the backend to how async and await in other languages work?

Edit2: I do have an RTOS for other projects but this specific question, assume no threads/tasks, just bare metal superloop.

Comment: Threads and job queues.

Comment: Do you have an OS?

Comment: No RTOS, no threads.

Comment: See [coroutines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine), particularly the implementation section. It's not possible to write a portable implement of coroutines in C (unless you use threads, assuming you think threads are portable) but libraries exist fir many platforms.

Comment: Could you provide a [example]? I feel it difficult to follow your description, even though I'm in embedded control for 30+ years and had a lot of systems doing parallel stuff on bare metal without any OS.

Comment: Either get an OS, or write your own kernel.  You need threading.  Put all of your output handling in a queue and process that from a period interrupt.  Collect all of your input on device interrupts if you can, or poll those on a periodic interrupt.

Comment: @jumpifnot0: It's not completely clear how your system works from the description. I am presuming that these actions are executed in a separate interrupt? Or you are waiting for an interrupt to signal the completion of the operation? In either case, there is no need to poll for changes all the time if you have a completion event - this is the transition point, i.e. the place where a callback would be invoked to continue with the next step. It would be best if you added some additional details.

Comment: @jwdonahue Yes, this was the answer to my poorly worded question. In order to avoid the complexity of continually managing states while still having a nice place to write easy to read and maintaine sustainable code, the answer is threading or coroutines. 

I was initially trying to avoid complexity but backed myself into a corner where which the obvious solution seemed like the worst case. The answer without going full operating system is to deploy a managed state/contex switcher.

Comment: @rici See the comment above this one. Coroutines are basically what I was getting at in lieu of a full RTOS. If you could elaborate on co-routines and optiobs that are appropriate for embedded (a lot of options for posix and pthreads, not many for embedded) I think it would make a good solution to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicament is a perfect fit for state machines (really, probably [UML statecharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)).  Each different request can each be handled in its own state machine, which handle events (such as **COMPLETE** or **ERROR** indications) in a non-blocking, run-to-completion manner.  As the events come in, the request's state machine moves through its different states towards completion.

For embedded systems, I often use the [QP event-driven framework](https://www.state-machine.com/) for such cases.  In fact, when I looked up this link, I noticed the very first paragraph uses the term "non-blocking".  The framework provides much more than state machines with hierarchy (states within states), which is already very powerful.

The site also has some good information on approaches to your specific problem.  I would suggest starting with the site's [Key Concepts](https://www.state-machine.com/doc/concepts) page.

To get you a taste of the content and its relevance to your predicament:

> In spite of the fundamental event-driven nature, most embedded systems
>   are traditionally programmed in a sequential manner, where a program
>   hard-codes the expected sequence of events by waiting for the specific
>   events in various places in the execution path. This explicit waiting
>   for events is implemented either by busy-polling or blocking on a
>   time-delay, etc.
>
> The sequential paradigm works well for sequential problems, where the
>   expected sequence of events can be hard-coded in the sequential code.
>   Trouble is that most real-life systems are not sequential, meaning
>   that the system must handle many equally valid event sequences. The
>   fundamental problem is that while a sequential program is waiting for
>   one kind of event (e.g., timeout event after a time delay) it is not
>   doing anything else and is not responsive to other events (e.g., a
>   button press).
>
> For this and other reasons, experts in concurrent programming have
>   learned to be very careful with various blocking mechanisms of an
>   RTOS, because they often lead to programs that are unresponsive,
>   difficult to reason about, and unsafe. Instead, experts recommend [...] event-driven programming.

You can also do state machines yourself without using an event-driven framework like the QP, but you will end up re-inventing the wheel IMO.

Comment: So, YES, on possible way to do this is statemachines. However... The core of the issue here that I didn't communicate well is that it's statemachine inside a statemachine inside a statemachine, all to keep the system doing the functional things that need to be while providing a way for clean procedural code to be written in sustainable way. The answer is threading - which I was avoiding for complexity reasons, but turns out there is no free lunch!

Comment: I'll look up QM's product again and see if it clicks this time. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sure thing, no problem.  Usually the answer is either "threads" or "state machines", or even both together (for some reason, many people consider multithreading and statemachines to be incompatible / mutually exclusive).  Often with multi-threading, the system becomes a set of coupled threads, pending on mutexes, lots of context switching, etc.  You can really do a lot with state machines running on "bare metal" though.  Good luck!!

Comment: "(for some reason, many people consider multithreading and statemachines to be incompatible / mutually exclusive)" Reminds me of some of the best RTOS advice I received: "You need as many threads, as you need separate statemachines". Meaning once you hit the limit, spool up a thread, cuts the exact issue of locking and messaging down to a minimum.